# Raspberry Pi 3 Increasing FPS with 720p USB Camera

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, raspberry-pi, jpeg

I write some code in python to open USB camera and grab frame from it. I use my code for http stream. For JPEG encode I use libturbojpeg library. For this I use 64 bit OS.

```
product: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
serial: 00000000f9307746
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smp cp15_barrier setend swp
```

I do some test with different resolutions.

```
Resolution   FPS   Time for encode
640 x 480     ~35       ~0.01
1280 x 720    ~17       ~0.028
```

And this is my code

```
import time
import os
import re
import uvc
from turbojpeg import TurboJPEG, TJPF_GRAY, TJSAMP_GRAY
jpeg = TurboJPEG("/opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libturbojpeg.so")
camera = None

import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

class ProcessJPG(Thread):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.jpeg_data = None
        self.data = data
        super(ProcessJPG, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.jpeg_data = jpeg.encode((self.data))

    def get_frame(self):
        self.frame = camera.get_frame()

global camera
dev_list = uvc.device_list()
print("devices: ", dev_list)
camera = uvc.Capture(dev_list[1]['uid'])
camera.frame_size = camera.frame_sizes[2] // set 1280 x 720
camera.frame_rate = camera.frame_rates[0] // set 30 fps

class GetFrame(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        super(GetFrame, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        self.frame = camera.get_frame()

_fps = -1
count_to_fps = 0
_real_fps = 0
from time import time
_real_fps = ""
cfps_time = time()

while True:
    if camera:
        t = GetFrame()
        t.start()
        t.join()
        img = t.frame
        timestamp = img.timestamp
        img = img.img
        ret = 1
    t_start = time()
    t = ProcessJPG(img)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    jpg = t.jpeg_data
    t_end = time()
    print(t_end - t_start)
    count_to_fps += 1
    if count_to_fps >= _fps:
        t_to_fps = time() - cfps_time
        _real_fps = 1.0 / t_to_fps
        cfps_time = time()
        count_to_fps = 0
    print("FPS, ", _real_fps)
```

Encoding line is: `jpeg.encode((self.data))`

My question is, it **is  possible to increase FPS for 1280 x 720** (eg 30fps) resolution or should I use more powerful device? When I look on htop during the computation CPU is not used in 100%.

EDIT:
Camera formats:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa705c0] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x480 1280x720 960x544 800x448 640x360 424x240 352x288 320x240 800x600 176x144 160x120 1280x800
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa705c0] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 640x480 1280x720 960x544 800x448 640x360 800x600 416x240 352x288 176x144 320x240 160x120
```

[image]

Comment: Can you enumerate the formats that the camera can capture? You might be able to configure it to return Jpeg encoded frames.

Comment: @jamieguinan I check this and updated question. There is two formats raw and compressed. Question is it possible to open camera in compressed mode?

Comment: It is definitely possible from the C code level - I have a Logitech C310 that can read mjpeg frames at 1280x720@25fps on an RPi2. But I don't know how/if your python library provides access to set the frame format. What library are you using for `import uvc`? Have you tried skipping the ProcessJPG() step and doing something like `print(dir(img))`? It is possible that the code is doing a redundant decompress -> compress.

Comment: I'am using python binding for libuvc library it's call pyuvc.Output of dir `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__pyx_vtable__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'avaible_modes', 'bandwidth_factor', 'close', 'controls', 'frame_mode', 'frame_rate', 'frame_rates', 'frame_size', 'frame_sizes', 'get_frame', 'get_frame_robust', 'name', 'stop_stream']`

Comment: In the source code I see https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/blob/master/uvc.pyx#L530 `UVC_FRAME_FORMAT_COMPRESSED` full list https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/blob/9e82cf52aa1530e55510da56a11a16a0db31c244/cuvc.pxd

Comment: When I save raw array it's has ~ 2.5 MB

Comment: I can't help feeling think `t.start()` followed immediately by `t.join()` is not at all useful. It starts another thread and then explicitly does nothing itself whilst waiting for it to finish, so it doesn't introduce any parallelism at all. The idea of threads is that you run several in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and you don't need more powerful hardware.

From the [pyuvc
README.md](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/blob/master/README.md),

`* Capture instance will always grab mjpeg conpressed frames from cameras.`

When your code accesses the `.img` property, that invokes `jpeg2yuv` (see
[here](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/blob/master/uvc.pyx#L251) and
[here](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/blob/master/uvc.pyx#L242)). Then
you are re-encoding with `jpeg_encode()`. Try using `frame.jpeg_buffer` after
the capture and don't touch `.img` at all.

I took a look at pyuvc on an RPi2 with a [Logitech
C310](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c310) and made a
simplified example,

```
import uvc
import time

def main():
    dev_list = uvc.device_list()
    cap = uvc.Capture(dev_list[0]["uid"])
    cap.frame_mode = (1280, 720, 30)
    tlast = time.time()
    for x in range(100):
        frame = cap.get_frame_robust()
        jpeg = frame.jpeg_buffer
        print("%s (%d bytes)" % (type(jpeg), len(jpeg)))
        #img = frame.img
        tnow = time.time()
        print("%.3f" % (tnow - tlast))
        tlast = tnow
    cap = None

main()
```

I get ~.033s per frame, which works out to ~30fps at ~8%CPU. If I uncomment the `#img = frame.img` line it goes up to ~.054s/frame or ~18fps at 99%CPU (the decode time limits the capture rate).

Comment: Wherever you end up decoding the jpeg frames, you will probably have to
[insert huffman
tables](https://github.com/pupil-labs/libuvc/blob/master/src/frame-mjpeg.c#L161)

Comment: Ok. So when I would like to display jpeg_buffer I must convert this into array ant reshape?

Comment: Depends where and how you are displaying it. If you are shipping the frames over http you can send the jbeg_buffer data as-is, it is common for mjpeg streams to lack the huffman tables. What will be on the receiving end, if you don't mind me asking? More Python code?

Comment: When I stream frame.jpeg_buffer into the browser there is no display. I try reshape jpeg buffer into (720, 1280, 3) but I gets `cannot reshape array of size 125576 into shape (720,1280,3)`. For example how to save `jpeg_buffer` as single file? Or if I stream `frame.jpeg_buffer` how client can display this?

Comment: Main question is how to easy do `mjpeg2rgb`?

Comment: I don't think the jpeg is reshapable. For BGR (close enough to RGB), you can just access the `.bgr` property and not re-compress it. If you are serving over http, you need to add some headers and `multipart/x-mixed-replace` stuff. [Example](https://github.com/radicalrabbit/PyMjpegServer/blob/master/src/mjpegStreamServer.py) that you might be able to adapt.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I check this. Yes, `frame.img` return `yuv` picture and this format has 3D array of shape (720, 1280, 3). So the best option is serve `jpge_buffer` over network becasue is most light?

Comment: Definitely. It will be ~125KB/frame instead of ~1.3MB/frame. stackoverflow is suggesting to move this to chat, feel free to continue there.